# Using Kafka Connect Replicator inside same Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I consider to use Kafka Connect replicator for event enrichment inside the same cluster.

The idea is to have SMT that will enrich the events and after that the events needs to be sent to Mongo DB & S3 bucket.
I understand that KStream / Flink are alternatives.

My question is: Is it a "make sense" design or I am missing something here?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replicator is intended to be used between clusters, not within the same. (It's also a paid feature, and you could just use MirrorMaker2 instead to do the same, if it were a possible solution).

KStreams / ksqlDB is meant for a transferring data within a cluster and seems to be the best option here.

Flink, Spark, or other stream processing tools would work, but require an external scheduler, and can themselves write to Mongo, S3, etc without the need of Kafka Connect, so really depends on how flexible you need the solution to be.

Comment: Thanks. Can I "inject" logic ( as SMT ) into MirrorMaker 2? Note that my Kafka is MSK.

Comment: MM2 is also built on Connect framework, so yes.

Comment: If you are in AWS, you could also use MSK lambda triggers and produce to new topics.